# my U-Net model can't predict pictures in the local env

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, prediction

I get nothing when using my model to predict pictures in my env.
Then I try same steps on the colab.
It's work!!!!

Why does it happens?

here is the code:

```
SIZE = 256
num_images = 2124 #1080+1044
image_names = glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/remake_pic/*.png")
image_names.sort()
image_names_subset = image_names[0:num_images]
images = [cv2.imread(img, 0) for img in image_names_subset]
image_dataset = np.array(images)
image_dataset = np.expand_dims(image_dataset, axis = 3)
image_dataset = image_dataset /255.
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/result/3plus_new_550_re_0.hdf5", compile=False)
y_pred=model.predict(image_dataset)
```

Comment: Did you update the path to the images?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.